# Cannot connect USB device to VMware Workstation 12.5

Tags: vmware, vmware-workstation

I want to have the USB HDD at `/dev/sdc` accessible to VMware Workstation 12.5 (Manjaro Linux host).

[Workstation 12 Pro Documentation Center](https://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-12/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.ws.using.doc%2FGUID-95232C52-C5A8-471B-A6A1-C7323A97FECA.html) says:

> On Linux hosts, Workstation Pro uses the USB device file system to connect to USB devices. If the USB device file system is not located in `/proc/bus/usb`, you must mount the USB file system to that location.
>
> ---
>
> **Important**
>   Do not attempt to add a USB drive device node directory, for example, /dev/sda, to the virtual machine as a hard disk.

I try to mount `/proc/bus/usb` as reccommended (same link as above):

```
[tara ~]# mount -t usbfs none /proc/bus/usb
mount: mount point /proc/bus/usb does not exist
[tara ~]# mkdir /proc/bus/usb
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/proc/bus/usb’: No such file or directory
[tara ~]# ls /proc/bus
input  pci
[tara ~]# uname -a
Linux tara 4.8.15-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Dec 15 22:22:45 UTC 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[tara ~]#
```

In my net trawling, it seems that `/proc/bus/usb` was removed in Linux kernel 3.5.

Surely it is possible to connect a USB device to VMware Workstation - how is it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `vmware-usbarbitrator`:

```
# vmware-usbarbitrator
```

To see what it is going on behind the scenes, run:

```
# vmware-usbarbitrator --kill && vmware-usbarbitrator -f
```

You may need to close and re-open `vmware` to see the changes.